# Can I increase UI scaling in eclipse on Mac?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, ide, scaling, text-size

I've spent some time already searching for an answer. I know that I can increase the text size in an open file, but is there any way to increase the overall UI scaling? I have a large monitor so I can utilize multiple applications in my workflow, but the size of the application text and icons is so small that it's totally unusable.

Here is a comparison between Eclipse on the left and IntelliJ on the right on my screen:

[image: eclipse ui smaller than intellij]

I scaled IntelliJ on the right to be the perfect size, easily, but Eclipse on the left is way too small to effectively work with it.

I've tried removing a line indicating small text in the eclipse.ini file but that didn't change anything.

Given how poorly my search has turned up already, I assume the answer is 'no'. This leads me to ask, how is this possible? How can such a sophisticated and popular application not be able to change the UI scaling? I feel as though there must actually be a reasonable explanation because this is just plain absurd. This can't be passed off as a legitimate piece of software in this day and age without flexibility on screen size.

Thank you.

- EDIT: *

I'm still unable to update the size of the UI icons. I've searched through numerous other issues going through the "-Dswt.autoScale=200" options in the elipse.ini setting but this is not working on Mac. Anyone able to assist here? Thank you!

Comment: What scaling are you using on the display? On my 27" iMac screen with "default for display" it looks fine (fairly small but perfectly readable)

Comment: The display is 3440 x 1440.  I want to work concurrently with other applications so it would defeat the point to drop the resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Tree and Table font for views" setting in the "General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts" page of the Preferences sets the size of Project Explorer view. That entry is in the "View and Editor Folders" section.

Icons are only scaled if the display is set up as scaled by x2 or x1.5.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449, this definitely helps and makes more sense. I suppose I wasn't expected to have to modify each of these individually but the flexibility does seem useful. I was expecting there to be a general UI scaling option which would work for other visual elements as well. Was operating in haste due to my biased expectations.

Comment: Hi @greg-449 Thank you for your answer, the text size helped but I've edit my question to include issues with the icon scaling.

Comment: Icons are only resized when the display is set up as x2 or x1.5 scaling.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried -Dswt.autoScale=150,200, and 300, none of them have changed the size :(